# Remove pointer to object from NSMutableArray while keeping object?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsmutablearray

I am trying to remove a pointer in an NSMutableArray that points to an object in another array without deleting the object itself. E.g.:

```
// In ViewController.m – Code abridged and somewhat simplified

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objectPool;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objectsOwnedByFriend;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objectsOwnedByMe;
- (void)transferPointerToObjectFromFriendToMe;
- (void)copyPointerToObjectFromFriendToMe;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize objectPool = _objectPool;
@synthesize objectsOwnedByFriend = _objectsOwnedByFriend;
@synthesize objectsOwnedByMe = _objectsOwnedByMe;

- (void)setObjectPool:(NSMutableArray *)objectPool
{
    _objectPool = objectPool;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)objectPool
{
    if (!_objectPool) _objectPool = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.objects]; // self.objects is a mutable array containing multiple NSObjects
    return _objectPool;
}

- (void)setObjectsOwnedByFriend:(NSMutableArray *)objectsOwnedByFriend
{
    _objectsOwnedByFriend = objectsOwnedByFriend;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)objectsOwnedByFriend
{
    if (!_objectsOwnedByFriend)
    {
        _objectsOwnedByFriend = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [_objectsOwnedByFriend addObjectsFromArray:self.objectPool];
    }
    return _objectsOwnedByFriend;
}

- (void)setObjectsOwnedByMe:(NSMutableArray *)objectsOwnedByMe
{
    _objectsOwnedByMe = objectsOwnedByMe;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)objectsOwnedByMe
{
    if (!_objectsOwnedByMe) _objectsOwnedByMe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _objectsOwnedByMe;
}

- (void)transferPointerToObjectFromFriendToMe
{
    [self.objectsOwnedByMe addObject:[self.objectsOwnedByFriend lastObject]];
    [self.objectsOwnedByFriend removeLastObject];
}

- (void)copyPointerToObjectFromFriendToMe
{
    [self.objectsOwnedByMe addObject:[self.objectsOwnedByFriend lastObject]];
}

@end
```

In the above code, when I use transferPointerToObjectFromFriendToMe, removing the last object removes both the pointer to it in self.objectsOwnedByFriend (as I want) and also the object itself in self.objectPool (which I *don't* want to happen).

What I would like is an array (self.objectPool) that contains all of the actual objects and then two mutable arrays (self.objectsOwnedByFriend and self.objectsOwnedByMe) that contains pointers to objects in self.objectPool and the ability to add and remove more pointers referencing objects in self.objectPool to self.objectsOwnedByFriend and self.objectsOwnedByMe.

<del>Also, when I use either transferPointerToObjectFromFriendToMe or copyPointerToObjectFromFriendToMe, the object doesn't seem to be added properly, as a subsequent check via self.objectsOwnedByMe.count results in 0 instead of 1.</del>
SOLUTION = My lazy instantiation for self.objectsOwnedByMe was missing in my original code :S
I was able to check whether self.objectsOwnedByMe was properly created via:

```
NSLog(@"self.objectsOwnedByMe = %@", self.objectsOwnedByMe);
```

---

** My first StackOverflow question! ** I hope I was clear...couldn't find a a similar question so apologies if I missed an old thread. Let me know if you need more info to diagnose. (I am trying to learn Obj-C.)

Comment: Instead of editing your original question to include the solution you should actually submit an answer and mark that answer as selected.  Think about it from the perspective of someone searching for a answer coming from google. They like to find well posed questions and answers that have been accepted.

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO I hope you enjoy your stay

Comment: Now I see...hidden at the bottom of the page! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo :P Sorry peeps. In my actual code in Xcode I had:

```
- (void)setObjectPool:(NSMutableArray *)objectPool
{
    _objectPool = objectPool;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)objectPool
{
    if (!_objectPool) _objectPool = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.objects];
    return _objectsOwnedByFriend;
}
```

I think my mistake is super obvious (and if not, the mistake was that my getter for `objectPool` was returning `_objectsOwnedByFriend`...copy/paste error that I somehow missed).

Everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

This is very peculiar and confusing code.  I suspect the problem is that something is calling one of the setters, `-setObjectPool:` or `-setObjectsOwnedByFriend:`, with the array of the other object.  Those setters simply make the ivar refer to the object that was passed in.  Because of that, they are very prone to lead to objects being shared.

Typically, a property like that would be declared and implemented with `copy` semantics.

Comment: Hi Ken: I am still a bit confused by what you mean. I _do_ want the objects to be "shared" I think. I just want one source array that contains the actual objects (`self.objectPool`) and then other arrays that refer to those objects (`self.objectsOwnedByFriend`, `self.objectsOwnedByMe`) without any kind of manipulation on them.

Are you saying that `copy` is the only way to go? Surely there must be a way to do this without copying the actual object (e.g., if the objects is very large; or, if I do want one object I can manipulate that will subsequently affect all objects pointing to it).

Comment: If I understand you, you want independent arrays, but you want the arrays to point to the same objects as elements. What I'm saying is that you probably don't have independent arrays. You are probably making multiple ivars point to the same array. If you copy an array, it's a shallow copy. You get a new array but it still points to the same elements as the array that was copied, which is what you want.

Comment: Hi Ken: Thanks for the clarification. It seems like my issue is with `addObject:`. Since this brings up a whole new set of questions, I'll start a new thread and resolve this thread if the new thread resolves the issue (rather than asking new questions in these comments).

Comment: I've posted a new question that may or may not be the same as this but rephrased differently. If so, apologies! But hopefully the two can be merged if an answer is found...the trick is to figure out how to ask the right question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466863/how-to-add-pointer-to-an-nsobject-custom-subclass-to-an-nsmutablearray

Comment: Okay I am now back to the original question, as my `addObject` issue has been solved. `copy`-ing the object still doesn't seem to solve the problem, as `[self.objectsOwnedByFriend removeLastObject]` still also removes the object from `self.objectPool`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `self.objectsOwnedByMe` is never initialized and you are therefore always working with `nil` instead of an actual NSMutableArray.

Somewhere (perhaps in a custom getter for objectsOwnedByMe as below?) you need to create an array before you start using it:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)objectsOwnedByMe {
    if (_objectsOwnedByMe == nil) {
        _objectsOwnedByMe = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _objectsOwnedByMe;
}
```

This would explain both problems:  Since it is `nil` it never retains the objects and therefore they go away when removed from the other array, and also why they are never added to the _objectsOwnedByMe array.

Comment: Sorry, that was indeed in the code! I've updated the question to include the setter and getter for self.objectsOwnedByMe :S